# how to make all files get picked up by "git add ." for new project?

Tags: git

I've created a new NextJs project on my laptop. I'm trying to git push that new project to an empty bitbucket repo.  I've executed "git init" on the top-level folder of my local project.  Then when I execute "git add ." followed by "git status" the console writes out:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   .vscode/settings.json
```

Not sure why only that single file is returned by git status.  I would expect references to all files in that structure to be returned.  Any idea about why I'm seeing that behavior and what I can do to ensure that refs to all of the files in the folder structure are returned so I can use git push to push all of those files to the bitbucket repo?

Comment: the rest might already at committed in its current state, or explicitly excluded through .gitignore.

Comment: nope i haven't done any commits and there's nothing special about the gitignore that would exclude every other file

Comment: the problem is with the information you're giving is that it's *your word* against *a deterministic computer program's output*; that's kind of undecidable: I'm inclined to say that something on your computer is not as you say, because otherwise we wouldn't see what we're seeing otherwise!

Comment: looking for a git command that will overwrite any and all existing status - and mark all files as eligible to get picked up by "git add ." which will then allow me to git commit all of those files

Comment: again, these files are either explicitly ignored or already committed, so there's nothing to pick up. But you could just delete the .git directory, run `git init .` again and then `git add`. (git very rarely lies…)

Comment: please provide a fully reproducable example, as is, it is very hard to tell what you did, and therefore where the problem may be.

Comment: Are you inside of another repo already further up? From your description you wouldn't have any commits yet, but your status doesn't say "No commits yet". What does `git log` show?

Comment: can you run `git check-ignore -v <a/file/that/should/be/staged>` ?

Answer (score 0):

The command should add all the files, including subfolder, so I'm suspecting something else is causing that files aren't added. Since I don't know how the project structure looks I will just give some examples on what to look for:

Git only tracks files, so if you do `git add .` it will only add files, not empty folders.

Look at `.gitignore` if you have any or if you already committed but haven't pushed.

Hope some of it help, otherwise please share some more details.